# Interactive Manipulation Add or Remove from list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

I have a set of images:

```
im1 = Import[
   "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-\
blooms-67636.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beauty-bloom-blue-67636.jpg&fm=jpg"];
im2 = Import[
   "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15239/flower-roses-red-roses-\
bloom.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=bloom-blossom-desktop-backgrounds-15239.jpg&fm=\
jpg"];
im3 = Import[
   "https://images.pexels.com/photos/15242/flower-roses-bloom-blossom.\
jpg?cs=srgb&dl=bloom-blossom-flora-15242.jpg&fm=jpg"];
im4 = Import[
   "https://images.pexels.com/photos/36455/rose-red-flower-victor-\
hugo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=flora-floral-flower-36455.jpg&fm=jpg"];

imList = ImageResize[#, 45] & /@ {im1, im2, im3, im4};
Grid[Partition[imList, 2]]
```

... and a list, which list numbers corresponding to an image:

```
imKeep = {1,2,3,4}
```

Now I am intersted to construct an interactive Grid. When I click with my mouse on an image, it should turn gray and the appropriate number should be taken out from the list `imKeep`.

When I click again on the same image, the image color should reapear and also the corresponding number in `imKeep`.

Example:

```
imKeep = {1,2,3,4}
```

[image]

I click on an image:

[image]

and imKeep becomes: `imKeep = {1,3,4}`

when I click again on the image:

[image]

-> `imKeep = {1,2,3,4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
im = {}; 
Row[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[im], Thread[Range[4] -> imList]], Dynamic[Sort[im]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

If you need to arrange togglers in a grid:

```
Row[{Grid[{{TogglerBar[Dynamic[x], Thread[{1, 2} -> imList[[;; 2]]]]}, 
    {TogglerBar[Dynamic[y], Thread[{3, 4} -> imList[[3 ;;]]]] }}], 
  Dynamic[Sort[Join[x, y]]]} , Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !! How do I do it, if I have a for example 2*10 images ?

Comment: @james, to arrange 20 images in two rows  you can use `Row[{Grid[{{TogglerBar[Dynamic[x], Thread[{Range[10] -> imList[[;;10]]]]}, 
    {TogglerBar[Dynamic[y], Thread[Range[11,20] -> imList[[11 ;;]]]] }}], 
  Dynamic[Sort[Join[x, y]]]} , Spacer[10]] `